# Formatting YYYYMM to MMMYYYY in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, formatting, ssrs-2014

I would like to to format one of my data fields to be in the date format of MMM YYYY.  For example, if "201209" is being returned, then I would like it to be displayed as Sep 2012.  On the SQL side I am using a CAST to only look at the Year and Month, normally this field would look like "20120914".  Here is what I used in the procedure:

```
cast(left(cast(TransactionDateKey as varchar(100)), 6) as int)
```

Within SSRS, I use the following code:

```
=Format(DateValue(MonthName(Right(Fields!Month.Value, 2))
 + "," + 
 Left(Fields!Month.Value,4)), "Y")
```

however the output is "September 2012", how would I go about get the abbreviation "Sep", instead of the full month name?

Comment: If at all possible you should change your database so it is a datetime datatype instead of an int or varchar which is what it sounds like you have. This isn't always possible so what you really should do is pass a date(or  datetime) datatype to your report. Then do the formatting based on the date datatype.

Comment: @Sean Lange -- very true; just remember, in many organizations, changing a database can be an extremely daunting task!

Comment: @JosephDoggie hence this part. "This isn't always possible". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another Option is Format() in SQL Server

```
Select Format(CONVERT (date,convert(char(8),TransactionDateKey )),'MMM yyyy')
```

For example

```
Select Format(CONVERT (date,convert(char(8),20120914 )),'MMM yyyy')
-- Returns Sep 2012
```

I should note that Format() is not known for its performance, but does offer some nice features

Comment: Thanks for getting back with me, however when I get rid of my casting statement and replace it with you suggestion, MMM yyyy is returned instead of a value

Comment: @Istaley Two questions.  1) is TransactionDateKey a date or datetime field?  2) Are you running the Format() in SQL Server (not SSRS)

Comment: 1)  TransactionDateKey in our fact table is an int.  I casted it above to cut off the day just to leave YYYYMM.  I am making a matrix report and we want to know the amount of fills a person has for each month, not each day.  Maybe there is a better way than to do a cast, but I am not sure.  2)  Yes, I tried Format() is SQL Server

Comment: @Istaley Then you simply have to cast the int (yyyymmdd) as a date.  So try  Select Format(cast(TransactionDateKey as date),'MMM yyyy')

Comment: I get the following error in SSMS "Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed"

Comment: @Istaley with the convert as listed above?

Comment: @Istaley Never understand why folks store dates as INTs.  You will always have to perform conversions

Comment: I apologize John, I didn't get the alert of your update and I tried the cast statement you gave me.  The one at the very top worked!!  Thanks so much!  I can't anything about the int thing, I am just a foot-soldier, but I do agree with you.

Comment: @Istaley No apologies.  I figured you inherited it.  Trust me, I've inherited far worse.  cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are returning an actual `datetime` field in your dataset - which is what your `TransactionDateKey` appears to be - you can handle the formatting completely in an SSRS expression using `format`:

```
=format(Fields!TransactionDateKey.Value,"MMM yyyy")
```

If you are returning your `yyyyMM` for grouping purposes, there is nothing stopping you grouping on a `datetime` value of the first of the month for `TransactionDateKey` within your SQL:

```
select dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,TransactionDateKey),0) as FirstDayOfTheMonth
```

If you ***absolutely need to*** return a `varchar` in the format `yyyyMM`, you can convert it to `MMM yyyy`, though you first need to convert it to a `date` in your expression - slashes and all - before SSRS will play ball:

```
=format(cdate(left(Fields!Month.Value,4) & "/" & right(Fields!Month.Value,2) & "/01"), "MMM yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

In SSRS you can use:

```
=StrConv(LEFT(
MONTHNAME(REPLACE(RIGHT(Fields!Month.Value,2),"0","")),3
),vbProperCase,NOTHING) & " " & LEFT(Fields!Month.Value,4)
```

Which returns `Sep 2012` for `201209`.

Let me know if this helps.